# Understanding Eclipse Job Family

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, jobs, belongs-to

I am learning Eclipse Job API but I couldn't find any documentation regarding how to use family class with an example. I am trying to create 3 jobs in which first two belong to same family and other one belong to the different family. I am not able to create a job which can refer to a particular family.

the code is given below:
   First file containing Job description

```
    public class Jobsclass{



        public static void eclipsejobsfamily() {

            Job MyFirstJob = new Job("My First Job") {
             protected IStatus run(IProgressMonitor monitor) {
                   System.out.println("Hello World (1st from a background First job)");
                   return Status.OK_STATUS;
                }
            public boolean belongsTo(Object family) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
              if (Jobsutil.MY_FAMILY.equals(family)) { return true; }
            return false;
            }
             };


            Job MySecondJob = new Job("My Second Job") {
             protected IStatus run(IProgressMonitor monitor) {
                   System.out.println("Hello World ( 2nd from a background Second job)");
                   return Status.OK_STATUS;
                }
            public boolean belongsTo(Object family) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
              if (Jobsutil.MY_FAMILY.equals(family)) { return true; }
            return false;
            } 
            };



            Job MyThirdJob = new Job("My First Job") {
             protected IStatus run(IProgressMonitor monitor) {
                   System.out.println("Hello World (1st from a background First job)");
                   return Status.OK_STATUS;
                }
            public boolean belongsTo(Object family) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
              if (Jobsutil.THE_FAMILY.equals(family)) { return true; }
            return false;
            } 
            };





             MyFirstJob.wakeUp();
             MyFirstJob.schedule();
             MySecondJob.setPriority(Job.SHORT);
             MySecondJob.schedule(); 
             MyThirdJob.wakeUp();
             MyThirdJob.schedule();


        }

        protected IStatus run(IProgressMonitor monitor) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }

    }

FILE 2: 
public class Jobsutil {
    public static final String MY_FAMILY = "myJobFamily";
    public static final String THE_FAMILY = "theOtherFamily";
}

public JobAction() {
    }
THIRD Class Method RUN():
    /**
     * The action has been activated. The argument of the
     * method represents the 'real' action sitting
     * in the workbench UI.
     * @see IWorkbenchWindowActionDelegate#run
     */
    public void run(IAction action) {
        MessageDialog.openInformation(
            window.getShell(),
            "LearnJobAPI",
            "First example");



             if (Jobsutil.MY_FAMILY.equals("myJobFamily")){

                }

             //Job.getJobManager().find("MY_FAMILY");
             //Job.getJobManager().wakeUp("MY_FAMILY");
           // Jobsclass.eclipsejobsfamily();
            this.manager.wakeUp(Jobsutil.MY_FAMILY);
            Job[] jobscreated= this.manager.find(Jobsutil.MY_FAMILY);

             Jobsclass.eclipsejobsfamily();
    }
```

Thanks in advance. Please help me understand how to control Job using family.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Job` classes must override the `belongsTo` method to define which families they belong to:

```java
Job myFirstJob = new Job("My First Job") {
     @Override
     protected IStatus run(IProgressMonitor monitor) {
           System.out.println("Hello World (1st from a background First job)");
           return Status.OK_STATUS;
     }

     @Override
     public boolean belongsTo(Object family) {
        return family == MY_FAMILY;
     }
};
```

Note: Your `wakeUp` calls are doing nothing, just call `schedule` to run a job.

Also please follow the Java naming conventions - variable names start with lower case. Failing to do this upsets the Stack Overflow code formatter (among other things).

If you want to run the `Job` in different families you will have to pass in the family to the Job constructor. Something like:

```java
class MyJob extend Job
{
  private final Object jobFamily;

  MyJob(String name, Object family) {
    super(name);

    jobFamily = family;
  }

  @Override
  protected IStatus run(IProgressMonitor monitor) {
       System.out.println("Hello World (1st from a background First job)");
       return Status.OK_STATUS;
  }

  @Override
   public boolean belongsTo(Object family) {
     return family == jobFamily;
   }
}


Job myFirstJob = new MyJob("My First Job", "A");  // family 'A'

Job myFirstJob = new MyJob("My First Job", "B");  // family 'B'
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. After trying I could get this but what I couldn't get. How to run this job using family "MY_FAMILY". Like to run Jobs from Family "A" or Job from Family "B".

Comment: Added job class with a family parameter

Comment: I was able to understand the suggested code and implement it  Thank you for help. But still my problem is there that I created and scheduled 3 Jobs of (family A,family  B,family  B). How can I run Jobs only Belonging to Family B. I created something like this but it is not working:     private IJobManager manager = Platform.getJobManager(); and manager.wakeUp("B"); is this method ok or please suggest. Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: Job Families are really only supposed to be used to wait for jobs in the family to end. They are not used to control when a job starts. You should not schedule a job until you are ready for it to run. If you want more information ask a new question explaining clearly your problem (and accept this answer).